# Stopping two loops thread receiving and sending data continuously

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, daemon

I have some trouble using threads in python.
For some reasons I have to create 2 threads. Each thread is doing almost the same thing :
a loop that receive data and send them.
My problem is : I don't know how to stop those threads. The data are sent continuously.
I tried to use "KeyboardInterrupt" and "myThread.daemon", but the loop is still running in console.
So if you know a solution to stop them (with 'CTRL+C' or a 'Keypressed'), I would be gratfefull.

Here is the global functioning of my code :

```
#=========#
#Thread 1 #
#=========#
class ThreadEmissionSerie1(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run(self):

                variable = 0
                while 1:
                        try:
                                print "variable 1 : ", variable
                                variable += 2
                        except:
                                pass

#=========#
#Thread 2 #
#=========#
class ThreadEmissionSerie2(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run(self):
                variable = 0
                while 1:
                        try:
                                print "variable 2 : ", variable
                                variable += 3
                        except:
                                pass


print "starting the threads"

th_E1 = ThreadEmissionSerie1()
th_E2 = ThreadEmissionSerie2()

th_E1.daemon = True
th_E2.daemon = True
th_E1.start()
th_E2.start()
```

I hope someone can help me :)
This programme should run on Windows AND Linux
Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: Can you clarify your problem?   The code as shown above ends almost immediately after it starts - the main thread gets to the end, then the daemons are shut down (when they are the only threads left) and it stops.   If you add `while 1: pass` to the end of this code, it runs until you hit ctrl-C, then it exits.  What is the problem?

Comment: My problem is that the code never stops. I'm on Windows XP, using python2.7, and the programme is still running in the console while hitting ctrl-C.
Maybe you run it with windows console (it stops immediatly..)?
Try it on python shell oppenning it with IDLE

Comment: indeed, I tried on linux adding "while 1: pass" 
at the end, and it works. I don't get why on windows (python shell) it is not working well...

Comment: I was able to stop it using Shell->Restart Shell.   I can't explain why it keeps running: something wierd about the IDLE shell (maybe the shell itself is the main thread, so the daemon threads do not die in that case?)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: yep, you are right (therefore I removed my comment after testing properly). The program does stop. I had overlooked the `th_E1.daemon = True` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer is as I commented: under IDLE, the "module" is running with IDLE's shell as the main thread, so the daemon threads do not die.

Comment: Thanks, that's weird but probably true. thanks for your help !